# Temporarily disable Truecrypt pre-boot authentication

Tags: truecrypt

My home PC has a Truecrypt encrypted system volume and is therefore protected by pre-boot authentication. I've just accessed it via remote desktop and updated a driver. It needs a restart to take effect. This obviously causes a problem as I am not there to manually enter the pre-boot password. Is there a way of temporarily disabling pre-boot authentication so that I can perform a remote reboot which will come back up afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

No. This would be very insecure. Not to mention that a long enough password would probably no space to fit short of rather ugly hacks.